# What's the difference between from turtle import * and import turtle?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to use a book on python, and I understand that `from turtle import *` imports everything into the current namespace while `import turtle` just brings the module in so it can be called as a class. When I try the latter, though, it breaks.

```
>>> import turtle
>>> t = turtle.pen()
>>> t.pen.forward(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
   t.pen.forward(10)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'pen
```

However, using `from turtle import*`, assigning `pen` to an object and typing command `forward` works fine. This is not what the book says to do, but it is the only thing that works. What is happening?

Comment: as per your code, `t` is the result of the function `pen()`. It's the pen dictionary, and has no `forward`method, and even less a `pen.forward()` thing. see https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.pen . `turtle.forward(10)` should work, though.

Comment: Wait, why are you doing anything with `pen`? `turtle.pen` is used to configure pen attributes. It doesn't have anything to do with what you're trying to do.

Comment: Moving the default turtle forward would be `turtle.forward(10)`, not `t.pen.forward(10)`.

Comment: The `import` difference is covered in many other postings.  The basics of moving a turtle are covered in any `turtle` tutorial.  Please refer to these before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the books says something like:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.pen()
t.forward(10)
```

then it's probably a typo for:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Pen()
t.forward(10)
```

where `Pen` is a synonym for `Turtle` -- we've seen that problem here before.  (Lowercase `pen()` is a utility function that's rarely used except in error.)

> I understand that `from turtle import *` imports everything into the
>   current namespace while `import turtle` just brings the module in so it
>   can be called as a class

My recommendation: use neither.  Instead do:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle()

turtle.forward(10)
# ...
screen.exitonclick()
```

The reason is that Python turtle exposes two programming interfaces, a *functional* one (for beginners) and an *object-oriented* one.  (The functional interface is derived from the object-oriented one at library load time.)  Using either is fine but using both at the same time leads to confusion and bugs.  The above import gives access to the object-oriented interface and blocks the funcitonal one.